# Email newsletter software in OO PHP

Tags: email, php

I am looking for any email newsletter software that is implemented in object oriented PHP and that uses MySQL database.

Required features: simple mail forwarding, subscribing, plain text mail and html mail. Basically we want use the basic features and extend based on our requirements. Hence we are looking for object oriented PHP based implementation. It should be preferably open source.

I had a look at various softwares available: phplist, pommo and tellematic. None of these are OO PHP based.

Please don't close this as duplicate as I am specifically asking for OO PHP implementation.

Comment: @user22182: when you have additional information to your question, please modify original question ("edit" link). That way readers do not have to read all comments too to understand what's being asked.

Comment: Why are other users adding extra information to the question? Where are they getting this information from? Why are they corrupting the question and duplicating the text?

Comment: @BloodPhilia It seems your edit failed. You just duplicated text.

Comment: @DanielBeck Yes you are quite right, the OP posted a comment with the piece I edited in and just assumed it wasn't already in the question itself... Corrected

Answer (score 1):

Recommend a good newsletter software that can meet your demands!

PHPKode newsletter software that I have used for a long time and never unsatisfied with it.
Note:
Run on PHPKode: For blogging and personal sites that need a simple newslatter serving solution at low impression levels. All hosting, bandwidth, security costs included.

Personal Edition: For personal, non-commercial use only. That includes email support.

Enterprise Edition: For businesses of all sizes looking for a powerful, easy-to-use newsletter serving solution that includes support.

Hopefully can help you!